# Migrating Mailserver

Tags: web-server, email-server, migration

I have a server that is hosted a la http://mydomain.com
I'd like to create a new server, and install all software from scratch (onto a VM locally first, and then move the vm to a new host).

How can I test out things like email, etc. to make sure they are working prior to launching the new machine.

Comment: Ehr.. Try them out? ^^; I'm sorry but I think this question is a bit too vague..

Comment: Well what I was asking was how would I configure DNS for example so that I can test it locally before the changeover of DNS/IP addresses.

Comment: You may want to look at this [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/120647/how-do-you-test-a-new-email-filtering-system) which is about testing out alternail mail filtering solution but really covers a lot of generic methods for testing email.

Comment: Hi Zoredache.  Thanks... Wanna put that into the answer field so I can mark it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Zoredache: [How do you test a new email filtering system?](https://serverfault.com/questions/120647/how-do-you-test-a-new-email-filtering-system)